# SQL SERVER TRIGGER USING UPDATED VALUES

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I what to use a trigger to salve the dates of all the STATUS changes in my TICKETS table:
I did try it there is above, but it is responding: "Invalid object name 'UPDATED'".

```
CREATE TRIGGER TG_TICKETS_STATUS_HISTORY
ON TICKETS_TI AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ID INT
    DECLARE @STATUS INT

    SELECT @ID = ID, 
        @STATUS = STATUS
    FROM UPDATED 


    IF (@STATUS != (
        SELECT TOP 1 SH.STS_NAME
        FROM TICKETS_STATUS_HISTORY SH
        WHERE SH.ID = @ID
        ORDER BY SH.STS_DATE DESC
    ))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TICKETS_STATUS_HISTORY
        VALUES (@ID, @STATUS, GETDATE())
    END
END
```

Answer (score 2):

What you should have is something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TG_TICKETS_STATUS_HISTORY
ON TICKETS_TI AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO TICKETS_STATUS_HISTORY (ID,STS_NAME,STS_DATE)
select i.ID,i.Status,GETDATE()
from inserted i
    inner join (
     select ID,STS_NAME,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY STS_DATE desc) as rn
     from TICKETS_STATUS_HISTORY
    ) h
      on
         i.ID = h.ID and
         i.STATUS != h.STS_NAME and
         h.rn = 1

END
```

`inserted` (and `deleted`) is a [pseudo-table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) that can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. Assigning column values from it into a scalar variable (e.g.

```
SELECT @ID = ID, 
    @STATUS = STATUS
FROM INSERTED
```

) is just plain wrong.

---

If you just want to check for whether the status column value has changed (and don't need to lookup in the history table) we can make it even simpler:

```
INSERT INTO TICKETS_STATUS_HISTORY (ID,STS_NAME,STS_DATE)
select i.ID,i.Status,GETDATE()
from inserted i
    inner join
     deleted d
      on
         i.ID = d.ID and
         i.STATUS != d.STATUS
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `INSERTED` table instead of `UPDATED`, as update operations consist of a delete and an insert operation.

In `DELETED` table you'll find the old values, in `INSERTED` you'll find the new (updated) values.

Also, in your trigger declaration, you should use `FOR` keyword instead of `ON` referring to actions which should start the trigger.

Eg.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TG_TICKETS_STATUS_HISTORY
ON TICKETS_TI 
FOR UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN    
    INSERT INTO TICKETS_STATUS_HISTORY
    SELECT I.ID, I.STATUS, GETDATE()
    FROM INSERTED I
    INNER JOIN DELETED D 
       ON I.ID = D.ID 
       AND I.STATUS != L.STATUS
END
```

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're right, he should join UPDATED table to make insert of multiple rows. I focused on his syntax and concept error

Comment: I don't think you can use `#` in the name of a CTE, and you still need to eliminate the `@ID` reference inside.

Comment: Yep, @Damien_The_Unbeliever, i was going for the quick way :)